# How do I pass an array of tensors into the criterion/loss function in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent

My loss function gives an error:

```
self.loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

#### -- Snip ####

loss = self.loss_fn(predictions, targets) # Error here: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'
loss.backward()
```

My predictions are an array of tensors as follows:

```
predictions = []
for _ in range(100):
   prediction = MyNeuralNet(inputs)
   predictions.append(prediction)
```

How can I pass an array of tensors into my loss criterion function without getting the above error?

Comment: This error should be impossible, according to what you've shown. (`MSELoss` returns a tensor, not a list.) Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue—a [mre].

Comment: Ah yeh the comment was on the wrong line. Probably could have inferred that from context but oh well.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, it is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59043534/7802200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `torch.stack` I could fix my issue:

```
predictions = torch.stack(predictions)
loss = self.loss_fn(predictions, targets)
```